# Linear maps and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image: question]

Hello, I'm struggling to get anywhere with this question.

I know a map is linear if

$f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$

and

$f(ax)=a*f(x)$

I am also fairly familiar with eigenvalues for 2x2 matrices, but I'm not well adverse with general eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what $T^n$ means, and why you can look at "powers" of this map $T$? Also, do you understand proofs by induction? If so, you can prove part (a) using a proof by induction.

For part (b), what definition of "invertible" are you using in this course?

Comment: @user136072 t T is invertible means that rankT = m and nullityT = 0. I don't understand the notion of $T^n$. I have seen a couple of proofs by induction, however not in this context.

Comment: $T$ maps elements of $V$ to other elements of $V$; that's what $T \, : \, V \rightarrow V$ means. So, $T$ can be applied twice to the same element (i.e. $T(T(v))$, or $T(Tv)$, or $T^2 v$, is well-defined) because $T(v)$ (or $Tv$) also belongs to $V$, and $T$ can be applied to things that belong to $V$ (like $v$). So, $T^n v$ makes sense because each $Tv$ still belongs in $V$. If $T$ mapped $V$ to some other set $W$, on the other hand, we couldn't look at $T^2 v = T(Tv)$ because $Tv$ is in $W$, but $T$ can only be applied to things in $V$.

Comment: Anyway, $T^n$ just means $T$ applied $n$ times, i.e. $T^4 v = T(T(T(Tv))) = T^3(Tv)$. If this course requires formal proofs (so that you might have to use induction), what this means is that $T^n v = T^{n-1}(Tv)$; so, your induction step would be to assume that $T^{n-1} v = \lambda^{n-1} v$ and show that this implies $T^n v = \lambda^n v$ (using that $T^n v = T^{n-1}(Tv)$ and $\lambda^n = \lambda^{n-1}\cdot\lambda$). Check out geodude's answer below, he gives some great starting hints!

Answer (score 2):

For a): try first to write $T^2v$. It is $T(Tv)=T(\lambda v)$, and since $T$ is linear...

Then try with $T^3, T^4$, and you'll soon find a general rule.

For b), remember that the inverse means $T^{-1}T=I$ (identity). Now, $Iv=v$, and $T^{-1}(Tv)=$...

Try yourself!